# Проблема с установкой nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Вылазит ошибка: на команду sudo npm -i Перед этим я использовал nodejs из репозиториев и естественно sass не заработал так как версия старая. Посмотрел  [урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXS90CWSro4) Снес ноду.

Но как бы не доконца что делать??

> audited 5147 packages in 10.86s found 4 moderate severity vulnerabilities run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Вы уверены, что это ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте npm audit fix или npm audit :)
Рекомендую переустановить ноду, а потом снести её.

Comment: Делал npm audit fix и npm audit fix --force. Как бы сас не выполняется. Ну и заново gulp не устанавливается. Как снести полностью ноду? Ну и нормальную ссылку на установку ноды.

Answer (score 0):

все порешалось установкой nodejs  с помощью версионоого контроля ноды
[cсылка на мануал Установка с помощью nvm](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)